# Why do CSS libraries use a generic class and specific class rather than just a specific class

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

Perhaps there is a term for this that I don't know.  My google and stack overflow searches turn up nothing because I don't know what to search for.

Why do CSS libraries like [Font Awesome](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) and [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) use generic classes like `fa` and `btn` in combination with specific classes like `fa-gear` and `btn-primary`?  Why not just apply all styling directly to the specific class so you could use `fa-gear` or `btn-primary` only?

Since both of these libraries use Less or Sass, they could use extend functionality or mixins to easily apply common styles to all the specific classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before CSS preprocessors, people wrote plain old CSS. And knowing how to write plain old CSS is the key to why you can't just use mixins or extend to achieve what you want - you'll end up with a massive stylesheet. See below:

Also see the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself):

From the source:

```
.fa {
  display: inline-block;
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
  font-size: inherit;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

And the specific classes:

```
.fa-glass:before {
  content: "\f000";
}
.fa-music:before {
  content: "\f001";
}
.fa-search:before {
  content: "\f002";
}
.fa-envelope-o:before {
  content: "\f003";
}
```

Can you imagine if there was no generic class? The CSS would contain a lot of unnecessary repetition:

```
.fa-glass {
  display: inline-block;
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
  font-size: inherit;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.fa-glass:before {
  content: "\f000";
}
.fa-music {
  display: inline-block;
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
  font-size: inherit;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.fa-music:before {
  content: "\f001";
}
.fa-search {
  display: inline-block;
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
  font-size: inherit;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.fa-search:before {
  content: "\f002";
}
.fa-envelope-o {
  display: inline-block;
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
  font-size: inherit;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.fa-envelope-o:before {
  content: "\f003";
}
```

Comment: But didn't both bootstrap and font awesome start with Less from the beginning?

Comment: LESS and SASS are CSS pre-processors. Browsers cannot interpret LESS and they cannot interpret SASS - they have to be compiled to CSS and that CSS has to be downloaded by the browser for it to understand how to lay out your page. Be mindful of what your LESS/SASS files look like when they are compiled so that they don't contain unnecessarily duplicated code because that leads to large file sizes and slow load times.

Comment: While I appreciate the concern for the resulting file size, I think it is also overblown.  Also, with support for extend rather than just mixins the resulting CSS wouldn't have to be that much bigger.

Comment: @JeffWalkerCodeRanger - you're wrong, it's not overblown. Fontawesome has done a great job at balancing readable source and efficient file size. And you're also wrong about using extend, when you think about the several hundred classes that fontawesome has, the file size would've been much much larger using extend (although not as big as if you had to use mixins).

Comment: Do you have a reference for this?  Some place the creators of either bootstrap or font awesome discuss this?  I feel like you have given a possible reason, but am not sure it is *the* reason.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the file size being smaller when you have the generic classes, this also makes it easier to extend as a developer without having to use less/sass.

Say for example, i want to create a button, im going to create a `btn-foo` with css in my project that can get all the stuff from `btn` without me having to worry about it, i just need to have a `<button class='btn btn-foo' />`